# Calderón-Zygmund operators with positive kernel

Tags: harmonic-analysis, singular-integrals

Let $T$ be a Calderón-Zygmund operator. That is, $T$ maps $L^2(\mathbb{R}^d)$ to itself and satisfies the representation formula
$$
Tf(x) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}K(x,y)f(y)\, dy
$$
for all $f \in L^2$ with compact support and $x \notin \operatorname{supp} f$, for some kernel $K$ defined outside the diagonal and satisfying
$$
|K(x,y)| \leq C|x-y|^{-d},
$$
$$
\int_{|x-y|>2|y-z|} |K(x,y)-K(x,z)|\, dx \leq C
$$
and
$$
\int_{|x-y|>2|x-w|} |K(x,y)-K(w,y)|\, dy \leq C.
$$

If $\psi$ is any nonnegative $C^\infty_c$ function then $f \mapsto f \ast \psi$ is cleary a Calderón-Zygmund operator with positive kernel.

My question is, do there exist Calderón-Zygmund operators with positive kernels which are not so well-behaved. For example: does there exist a Calderón-Zygmund operator with a positive kernel which is not locally $y$-integrable near the diagonal $\{x=y\}$?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, the fact that some non-integrable kernels yield bounded operators is due to cancellation. Suppose $K$ is a nonnegative kernel which is nonintegrable with respect to $y$ along the diagonal. Let $f$ be the characteristic function of an open ball $B$. Then for every $x\in B$ we have 
$$Tf(x)=\int_B K(x,y)\,dy = \infty$$
which is rather far from having $Tf\in L^2$.

Comment: but you cannot use the representation formula for $x$ in the support of the function...

Comment: @Guillermo There is no problem of interpretation of integrals with nonnegative integrand. If you follow the procedure of restricting integration to $|y-x|>\epsilon$, the outcome is still the same: $T_\epsilon f$ is unbounded in $L^2$ as $\epsilon\to 0$.

Comment: you're completely right.

Comment: @PostNoBulls: A priori one doesn't know that if $T$ is a Calderon-Zygmund operator, then the truncations $T_{\epsilon}$ are uniformly bounded in $L^{2}$ norm. This takes a bit of work to show.

Answer (score 0):

A natural positive kernel, that satisfies the Calderón-Zygmund condition, but retains some singularity, could be the (positive) Bergman kernel in the upper half-plane. Namely, for points $z=x+iy$ and $w=u+iv$ in $\mathbb{R}^2_+$ (ie, $y,v>0$), define
$$
K(z,w)=\frac1{|z-\overline{w}|^2}=\frac1{(x-u)^2+(y+v)^2}.
$$
For each fixed $z$, one can check that $\int_{\mathbb{R}^2_+}K(z,w)\,dw=\infty$. As a consequence, the corresponding operator $T$ is not bounded in $L^1(\mathbb{R}^2_+)$ (just test with $f=\chi_{B_{1/2}(i)}$, so that $Tf(z)\approx \frac1{x^2+(y+1)^2}$ if $|x|\geq1$). On the other hand, it is well known (and not hard to show) that $T$ is bounded in $L^p(\mathbb{R}^2_+)$ for all $1<p<\infty$ (for example, one can use the Schur test). Also, $K(z,w)=K(w,z)$ satisfies the usual Calderón-Zygmund conditions, namely
$$
|K(z,w)|=\frac1{|z-\overline w|^2}\leq \frac1{|z-w|^2}
$$
and, for $|z-w_0|\geq 2|w-w_0|$
$$
\Big|K(z,w)-K(z,w_0)\Big|\leq \frac{C\,|w-w_0|}{|z-w_0|^3}. 
$$
This last condition is known to imply the integral condition stated above. In particular, the operator $T$ will also be bounded from $L^1\to L^{1,\infty}$, a fact which cannot be easily proved with elementary techniques (like the Schur test).  The kernel, however, is not "singular at the diagonal" as stated in the original question, since $K(z,\cdot)\in L^1(B_R(z))$, for all $z$. In this case, the singularity occurs at infinity.